# paypal adaptive payments in sandbox fails with error "The receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to receive payments"

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using paypal adaptive payments for auto recharge. Earlier it used to work fine in sandbox mode. My sandbox test account is in Australia, now adaptive payments fails with the error message "The receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to receive payments". Is paypal adaptive payments no longer supported in Australia? Thanks.

Comment: I'm from Spain and I can only send and receive payments if I create sandbox accounts assigned to the US. To make it worse, you apparently cannot change the country once the account is created so I had to remove and create again all my test accounts :(

Answer (score 1):

Seems like they (PP) switched all the sandbox accounts on US so you need now to update all the test accounts emails back to your country.

This is from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

"Import your existing Sandbox test accounts using the email address and password you used previously with the Sandbox. Make sure you import to the PayPal account that you want to use for development. You can import only once. Import data"

Also, from https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support/faq#non-US-dev

"I'm a non-U.S. developer. How does the site redesign affect me?
You can use our Classic APIs (like Checkout and PayPal Payments Standard) for new integrations. If you don't have a PayPal account, you can create a new Business account for your country.

If you've previously used our Classic APIs, you can continue to use them. You can import existing Sandbox accounts on the Sandbox Accounts page by using you old Sandbox email address and password.

Our REST APIs and the PayPal Mobile SDK are currently targeted only for the U.S. market. However, we'll be rolling them out to other countries over the rest of the year."

this doesn't sound so good I know ...

Comment: I have imported my sandbox accounts, and also created new test accounts in Australia. With both the existing and new test accounts adaptive payment fails with the error message "The receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to receive payments". However with US test accounts adaptive payment works fine. According to paypal documentation classic API should continue to work fine, not sure if adaptive payments falls under classic API or not.