# Paypal Sandbox is not working for Non-US developers using Paypal iOS SDK

Tags: ios6, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

In my iOS app , I have integrated the adaptive payment using paypal sdk from https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index

After paypal changed their site , I am not able to perform transaction using above library.

Here is my code

```
    -(void)processSplitPaymentWithFacebuyAdminPayPalId:(NSString*)adminId sellerPayPalId:(NSString*)sellerId withAdminPercentage:(NSNumber*)adminPercentage forTotalAmount:(NSNumber*)totalAmount andShippingCharges:(NSNumber*)shippingCharges
{
    NSLog(@"!!!--------------------------------------");
    NSLog(@"AdminID: %@",adminId);
    NSLog(@"SellerID: %@",sellerId);
    NSLog(@"Admin Percentage: %@",adminPercentage);
    NSLog(@"Total Amount: %@",totalAmount);
    NSLog(@"Shipping Charges: %@",shippingCharges);
    NSLog(@"!!!--------------------------------------");

    PayPal *ppMEP = [PayPal getPayPalInst];
    ppMEP.shippingEnabled = TRUE;
    ppMEP.dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = TRUE;
    ppMEP.feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;
    PayPalAdvancedPayment *payment = [[[PayPalAdvancedPayment alloc] init] autorelease];
    payment.paymentCurrency = @"AUD";

    payment.receiverPaymentDetails = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSArray *emails = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:adminId,sellerId, nil];

    for (int i = 0; i < emails.count; i++)
    {
        PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails *details = [[[PayPalReceiverPaymentDetails
                                                   alloc] init] autorelease];

        details.invoiceData = [[[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init] autorelease];

        float adminAmount = [adminPercentage floatValue];
        float sellerAmount = [totalAmount floatValue] - adminAmount;


        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // Admin commission
                details.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",adminAmount]];
                details.description = @"Amount payed to Admin as a Commission";
                details.merchantName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ADMIN];
                break;
            case 1:
                // Seller amount
                details.invoiceData.totalShipping = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",shippingCharges]];
                details.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",sellerAmount]];
                details.description = @"Amount payed to Seller";
                details.merchantName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",SELLER,@"Seller Name"];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        details.recipient = [emails objectAtIndex:i];
        [payment.receiverPaymentDetails addObject:details];
    }
    [ppMEP advancedCheckoutWithPayment:payment];
    [emails release];
}
```

But everytime I try to perform the transaction , I get below error

```
    errorId: 580022
message: The receiver is based in a country that isn't enabled to receive payments
```

My test accounts are created for Australia. My app will be available ONLY in Australia.

Now my question is
1) Does it matter even if my iOS app went in Production ?
2) Also can we use the iOS SDK given in above link or do we need to use latest SDK ?

I saw some [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541789/paypal-adaptive-payments-in-sandbox-fails-with-error-the-receiver-is-based-in-a) but I am not clear what's going wrong.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:

If I use US test accounts then still my transaction is not completed.

```
- (void)paymentFailedWithCorrelationID:(NSString *)correlationID
```

Above method gets called & here is the response

```
severity: None
category: Application
errorId: 0
message: None
```

Here is a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you switch over to our new Mobile Payment library for iOS? The old one is now deprecated and everyone is being encouraged to use the new library.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/

Comment: ah noticed that you are trying to use this in Australia. the new mobile payment library is currently supported only in US. Let me reach out to the team and see if they can help in troubleshooting what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Praveen for your reply. I can not switch to new library because of 2 reasons
1) I need to use app in Australia
2) I need adaptive payment
Please let me know if you get any information from your team.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like the old MPL library is not going to be supported anymore. Can you use the Adaptive Payments APIs with a webview integration (instead of mobile payment library) ?

Comment: My Client don't want to show web view. On paypal's site it is said that we will still provide support for older api & library. We will not deprecate it soon. Also new ios sdk is doesn't support adaptive payments & its for US only.

Comment: Can you suggest me any other option ?

Comment: Sorry - unfortunately there are no other options other than using web view for payments. Apologies for the confusion on the website about the support for the library.

Comment: Ok. I have 2 more question.

1) If Buyer wants to send the payment to 2 recipients out of which 1st is admin , so we have merchant account for admin. But 2nd recepient is seller which may be buyer. So do we need merchant account for seller as well or personal account will also work in Adaptive payments ?

2) If I use Web view , how will I get the transaction info i.e. transaction id , amount etc ?

Comment: One more thing , does MPL library doesn't support for SANDBOX OR LIVE environment ?

Comment: The second receiver can be any type of account but keep in mind unless an account is a premier or business - they might not have access to their own API Credentials, IPN, etc. that they might need to run their business.

When you use Adaptive Payments APIs (in a webview), you will get a PayKey returned upon a successful payment. You can do a PaymentDetails API using the PayKey to obtain the transaction ids.

Comment: MPL (both new and old) supports both Live and sandbox envs. Let me know which version you are using and I can tell you the specific code.

Comment: I am using PayPalMPL_1-6-0-iPhone_DevelopersPackage from https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index I am asking this because you said "Looks like the old MPL library is not going to be supported anymore. Can you use the Adaptive Payments APIs with a webview integration (instead of mobile payment library) ? " . I saw there is new version available on x.com which is PayPalMPL_1-6-5-iPhone_DevelopersPackage.zip Can I use this version to solve my problem OR I need to use WebView ONLY ? Thanks

Comment: The new version (PayPalMPL_1-6-5-iPhone_DevelopersPackage.zip) is to fix an expiring SSL cert. You can use it for now but as I said, the library itself is deprecated so I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Thanks Praveen for your kind support. I will let you know if I need anything

Comment: Can you tell me , how can I hide PayPal window shown modally when my iOS app enters background ? I need to hide PayPal window & navigate to previous view.

Comment: Can you help me with this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740647/paypal-sandbox-accounts-for-china-new-zealand Thanks