# Paypal sandbox accounts for China & New Zealand

Tags: ios6, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, country

I am using Paypal MPL for iOS. I am able to create sandbox accounts for USA , UK , AU & Hong kong in Paypal sandbox. In the specs sheet of Paypal MPL , China & New Zealand both are supported. But I can't find to create sandbox accounts for them.
Can anybody tell me how to create sandbox accounts for these country ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to developer.paypal.com with your usual account. After login, goto sandbox.paypal.com directly in a second tab/window in your browser. Click on SignUp and select the country/language combinations to create a test account in sandbox env. Once it's created it will be linked with your developer.paypal.com account automatically. Keep in mind - it's little painful process than creating a test account from developer.paypal.com as you would need to provide all the data like address, credit and bank accounts, etc.

Comment: Thanks Praveen for your reply. I will check it & let you know.

Comment: Can you help me with issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827245/invalid-parameter-subtotal-in-paypal-mpl-ios-sdk Thanks

Comment: I created the account for New Zealand , but it's NOT linked with my developer.paypal.com account. Also this account has 0 balance. How can I add balance to this account ?

Comment: hmm can you let me know it's id so I can find out why it's not linked with a developer.paypal.com account ? 

Btw to add balance - just send payment from another sandbox test account :-)

Comment: Paypal id of newly created sandbox account is buyernz@facebuy.com.au
On the sandbox accounts page it shows Total records: 11 but list shows only 10 records. I changed show 50 per page , still it shows 10 records only.

Comment: I sent payment from other sandbox account to newly created account , but it shows balance as $0.00 NZD. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong  ? Thanks

Comment: hmm did you check if the payment is pending for any reason? also if you've sent in any other currency other than NZD, the amount gets deposited as a different balance in that specific currency unless you configured your account to auto-convert to NZD. So login to sandbox.paypal, under myprofile/my money, you will see a link to balances - see what you find there.

Comment: btw will lookup your test account using internal tools tomorrow - the tools are dog slow over vpn from home. sorry for the delay.

Comment: Any update on this ? I still didn't get the payment in buyernz@facebuy.com.au sandbox account. Thanks

Comment: HK buyer made 1 transaction in HKD of 3.20 HKD. Now seller got only 0.74 HKD , remaining 2.46 HKD is paypal fee. This is approx 77% of total amount. Why this much fee for Paypal . In AUD its around 0.40 AUD for 2.30AUD. Can you comment on this ? Thanks

Comment: Can you have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987634/invalid-parameter-currency-in-paypal-mpl-sdk-for-ios Thanks

Comment: sorry for the delay in response (was on vacation) - can you give me the transaction Id for your HKD transaction so I can lookup the fee details? Assuming it's in sandbox.