# Invalid parameter : currency in PayPal MPL SDK for iOS

Tags: paypal, currency, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, ios6.0

I am using PayPal MPL SDK for iOS app. I am initiating the transaction for China using CNY currency. When I clcik on Pay with PayPal button , I am getting below error

```
Invalid parameter : currency
```

So I tried with RMB currency , still I got the same error. 
Can anybody tell me whats wrong in the currency for China ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RMB` is not a valid currency value for use in the Mobile Payment Library.

The Mobile Payment Library Guide for iOS has a list of currencies that are supported:
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_iphone.pdf

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried RMB as well as CNY. But for both the currency , I am getting the same error. So what do you suggest which currency shall I use for China users ?

Comment: In my answer I included a link to our iOS Mobile Payment Library guide. It has a list of currencies you can use. Neither CNY or RMB are supported currently.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I end up using USD.